# WooCommerce - find all classes and elements to customize via CSS

Tags: woocommerce, woothemes

I'm trying to modify the WooCommerce Shop, Cart, and Checkout page using CSS, and was wondering if there's a way to find out all the classes used in these pages.

The concept that I am following is the one suggested here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/css-structure/#section-2 where I can make changes on my theme's CSS. Like adding `a.button, button.button, input.button, #review_form #submit { background:black; }` to my theme's stylesheet, and so on.

Is there a way to know these classes, or do I have to manually inspect the elements in every page and modify them based on the classes visible in it? Any advices? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I always find it helpful to look at the base CSS files.

https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/tree/master/assets/css this is the current active repository for all WooCommerce CSS files (broken out).

The SCSS definitely DOES have the style commented by page if you want to focus on shop/cart/checkout.

If you download the current base files, remove the WooCommerce ones through functions:

```
// Remove each style one by one
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'jk_dequeue_styles' );
function jk_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-general'] );    // Remove the gloss
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-layout'] );     // Remove the layout
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-smallscreen'] );    // Remove the smallscreen optimisation
    return $enqueue_styles;
}

// Or just remove them all in one line
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
```

Then you can effectively override as needed directly from the "source" that won't conflict with future updates to Woo. If you ever wanted to update in the future, you could always do a DIFF using your overrides and Woo's CSS.

Or you could just grab the pieces you need :)